# "Ходатайствовать перед ..."

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Ходатайствовать перед ..."
Правильно ли это  - "перед" ?

Comment: "Ход**а**тайство" - поход, чтобы предстать, представить некое прошение, поэтому с ним использовались предлоги "к" или "перед" (*предстать **перед** царём*, например), мне думается.

Answer (score 3):

Для глагола"ходатайствовать" возможны три варианта:

1) **О чем**

Организация ходатайствует о поставках оборудования (с отвлеч.сущ.).

2) **За кого-что перед кем**

Заведующий ходатайствует за медсестру **перед главврачом**.

Профком ходатайствует за предоставление сотрудникам летних отпусков.

3) **С придаточным**

Мы ходатайствовали, чтобы план был утвержден в этом месяце.

Материал взят из "Словаря грамматической сочетаемости", РАН, 2013